# CodeBuild Windows Container Contents

Tags: aws-codebuild

AWS Provides curated environment images:

```
> aws codebuild list-curated-environment-images --region us-west-2
...
"name": "aws/codebuild/windows-base:1.0",
...
"name": "aws/codebuild/standard:1.0",
...
```

The contents of the UBUNTU images can be determined from the [git repo](https://github.com/aws/aws-codebuild-docker-images/tree/master/ubuntu/standard/1.0) but there's nothing about the WINDOWS_SERVER images in the repo.

Where can we find information about the contents of the WINDOWS_SERVER platform images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Dockerfile for Windows build image is not public. You can introspect the running container to look for clues or check what is already installed.

Comment: How would you introspect the running container?